# Validate.Custom not working -Livevalidation

Tags: javascript, livevalidation

I am trying to validate my select field using live validation

This my code

```
function validate()
    {   
        return LiveValidation.massValidate(totalValidationFields);
    }
function validateSelect(value)
    {
        alert('Validate select called');
        if(value==="0")
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

function addCustomValidation(id,msg)
    {
        var selectedvalue = $('#'+id+' option:selected').val();
        var fieldValidation=new LiveValidation(id);
        fieldValidation.add(Validate.Custom, { against: validateselect(selectedvalue), failureMessage: msg });
        totalValidationFields[i++]=fieldValidation;
    }
```

I want to validate my select field for 1st option. If it is selected then it should display custom validation message.

**[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/5xbw39p6/4/)**